# I haven't come. I didn't come

Tags: past-tense, present-tense

What's the difference between these two sentences, according to their meaning and structure:

> 1. I **haven't** come.
> 2. I **didn't** come.

Do they have the same meaning?

Comment: The first is in the Present Perfect, the second is in the Simple Past tense.

Comment: @CopperKettle beat me by a few seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to change the verb in the sentence:

1. I didn't eat.
2. I haven't eaten.

Both mean the person did not consume a meal during some timeframe. As others have said, the tenses are different.

> Did you eat yesterday?
>   **No, I didn't eat yesterday.**
>   <sub>(In this case, the simple past maps to yesterday)</sub>
>
> When was the last time you ate?
>   **I haven't eaten since last Friday.**
>   <sub>(In this case, the [present perfect](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/the-present-perfect-simple-tense/) refers to a time period starting last Friday and continues up to now.)</sub>

Similarly:

> Did you go to the see the new movie last Friday?
>   **No, I didn't go on Friday, I went on Saturday.**
>
> Have you gone to see the new movie yet?
>   **No, I haven't gone yet. I'm planning to go this weekend.**

When using the first person, I think we usually use *go* instead of *come* in conversations like these. However, we might say:

> Did he come to the family reunion last week?
>   **No, he didn't come. He had to work that day.**
>
> Has he come to any of the family reunions lately?
>   **No, he hasn't come to a reunion since 2007.**

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference of tenses. *'I haven't come'* is in Present perfect tense, whereas *'I didn't come'* is in past tense, more specifically, simple past. That's the obvious difference.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is basically the same. Both tenses talk about completed actions. But you use **present perfect** (as many other uses) to connect the past event with the present. Consider the following sentences where you cannot use the **present perfect**:

> *When I was a child, I **didn't** come to school on time.*
>   *When I was a child, I **haven't** come to school on time.*
>   (My school days are finished and no connection with the present is made.)